# chess AI for GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, artificial-intelligence, chess

I am looking for a Chess AI that can be run on Google App Engine. Most chess AI's seem to be written in C and so can not be run on the GAE. It needs to be strong enough to beat a casual player, but efficient enough that it can calculate a move within a single request (less than 10 secs).

Ideally it would be written in Python for easier integration with existing code.

I came across a few promising projects but they don't look mature:

- http://code.google.com/p/chess-free
- http://mariobalibrera.com/mics/ai.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong with [PyChess](http://pychess.googlepages.com/)?  It's pure Python, fairly mature, and will certainly be able to beat a casual player.

It's been a while since I've used PyChess, but a quick glance through [some of the source](http://code.google.com/p/pychess/source/browse/trunk/lib/pychess/Players/PyChess.py?r=1496)
*does* indicate that you can set a time limit on how long to search for a move.

The PyChess engine that is written in pure Python is in [pychess.Utils](http://code.google.com/p/pychess/source/browse/#svn/trunk/lib/pychess/Utils).  Specifically, if you look at [pychess.Utils.lutils](http://code.google.com/p/pychess/source/browse/trunk/lib/pychess/Utils/#Utils/lutils), you can see for instance [the move generator written in Python](http://code.google.com/p/pychess/source/browse/trunk/lib/pychess/Utils/lutils/lmovegen.py).

Comment: I had a look at pychess, but the chess engines it uses seem to be C based:
http://code.google.com/p/pychess/wiki/ChessEngines

Comment: @Richard: It does support C engines, through the CECPEngine and UCIEngine classes. However the engine it bundles, and which is used for internal analysis, is written in Python.

Comment: @Richard: Also consider to send stuff back upstream, if you make improvements or fixes to the code.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a poor match for the GAE architecture, which is designed for efficient CRUD operations, and not CPU-intensive tasks. In practice, anything that takes more than a few tens of milliseconds per request will blow out your CPU quota pretty quickly.

Comment: still, the free CPU quota is very generous at 6.5 hours. If the average AI move took ~3 CPU seconds (some are on book) and there are ~40 moves / game, then that would give me ~200 games / day, which is more than I need. (Hope my assumptions are correct)

Comment: Actually you can create strong engines with not that much cpu power, if you do it correctly.
A good chess engine prunes the tree so heavily, that the sum of nodes searched for, say, depth 7 is within 1sec of an interpreted language.

Comment: If you take more than about 500ms your process gets killed and your user gets an HTTP 500.

Comment: Where did you read that? The docs say 30 seconds and my experience confirms this.